# My driver class is not working with Ashot screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, ashot

I have a separate driver class which implements WebDriver and has all the common methods. I wrote another class called Screenshot util in which I wrote implementation of screenshots using Ashot, baseLinePageScreenshots(Driver driver, String name)  here name is screenshot and name driver is Driver class object. In my test case I called the above method and passed Driver class object only
`sutil.baseLinePageScreenshots(driver, method.getName());` but when I execute I facing following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Driver must have capabilities

Comment: Where is the screenshot?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to cast my driver class object to the WebDriver but it didn't work.